# Postgis не может преобразовать geojson

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Geojson:

```
{"features": [{"properties": {}, "type": "Feature", "geometry": {"coordinates": [[[38.9652, 56.513], [39.0421, 56.2616], [39.3525, 56.3715], [38.9652, 56.513]]], "type": "Polygon"}}], "type": "FeatureCollection"}
```

Проблема в том, что я пытаюсь его преобразовать в геометрию, в результате чего `postgres` ругается следующим образом:

```
ERROR:  invalid GeoJson representation
```

Делаю следующие действия:

- Создаю таблицу `create temporary table test (geojson text);`
- Создаю файл с двумя строками:

  > 0
  >
  > {"features": [{"properties": {}, "type": "Feature", "geometry": {"coordinates": [[[38.9652, 56.513], [39.0421, 56.2616], [39.3525, 56.3715], [38.9652, 56.513]]], "type": "Polygon"}}], "type": "FeatureCollection"}
- Загружаю данные из файла в БД, в таблицу:

  `copy test from /geojson_zones.csv' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;`
- Преобразовываю данные в геометрию:

  `select ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson)::geography from test;`
- В результате получаю вышеуказанную ошибку.

Следует отметить, что geojson валиден. Проверял [тут](http://geojsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась очень просто. Связана она с тем, что Postgis требует geojson немного у короченном формате:

Пример:

```
'{
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[
                [7.734375,51.835777520452],
                [3.8671875,48.341646172375],
                [7.20703125,43.580390855608],
                [18.6328125,43.834526782237],
                [17.9296875,50.289339253292],
                [13.7109375,54.059387886624],
                [7.734375,51.835777520452]
            ]]
        }'
```

Подробное обсуждение вопроса [здесь](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60928/how-to-insert-a-geojson-polygon-into-a-postgis-table).

Comment: Обращаю особое внимание, что нужно использовать массив массив массивов (3 шт). В противном случае будет создаваться пустой полигон